# Google Analytics Mobile Apps SDK for Windows Phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7, google-analytics-api

Does anybody know how would I be able to access the new Mobile Apps Analytics from a Windows Phone device? it seems they have SDKs only for Android and iOS but not any REST service anyway, have anyone looked into this? thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok looks like I found my answer :) http://googleanalyticssdk.codeplex.com/ this is what we need for the long term.

Comment: fyi: http://googleanalyticssdk.codeplex.com is the only framework that supports the new Google Mobile Apps Analytics (Universal Analytics). The other frameworks out there like GAT are all based on the now deprecated urchin (UTM) protocol.

Comment: Thanks @TimGreenfield looks like that's the case :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Microsoft Silverlight Analytics Framework](http://msaf.codeplex.com/). It was designed for Windows Phone in mind and should be your first choice when it comes to in-app analytics. It supports Google Analytics, among other services.

Also, here is now the Google Analytics SDK - you can get it on [CodePlex](http://googleanalyticssdk.codeplex.com/) and [NuGet](http://nuget.org/packages/GoogleAnalyticsSDK) (note: pre-release software).

Comment: Thanks but I don't think Analytics Framework uses the new mobile apps analytics, plus it's outdated, I would use https://github.com/maartenba/GoogleAnalyticsTracker better

Comment: Not sure about the mobile apps analytics, but sure - you could use the GAT from GitHub since it appears to carry support for both WP7 and WP8.